# Null check while combining the list in Jolt

Tags: jolt

Extracting values from first array element and second element and joining both. Input String:

Null or Empty check required.

```
[
  {
    "creationDate": "2020-04-01T14:14:32.685+0000",
    "factValues": [
      {
        "Factname": "Medicine",
        "factvalue": "1234556",
        "sourcePguid": "1"
      },
      {
        "Factname": "Journal",
        "factvalue": "123455",
        "sourcePguid": null
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "creationDate": "2020-04-01T14:14:32.685+0000",
    "factValues": [
      {
        "Factname": "chemical",
        "factvalue": "123455567",
        "sourcePguid": "2"
      },
      {
        "Factname": "Rubber",
        "factvalue": "123455435",
        "sourcePguid": "3"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Output excepted:

```
  {
       {
        "sourcePguid" : "1",
        "Medicine":"1234556"

      }, {
        "sourcePguid" : "2",
        "chemical":"123455567",
        "Rubber":"123455435"
      } 
    }
```

Kindly help me to achieve the expected output.json in spec.json. The spec is not transforming as expected output. I want learn how to use attributes inside the string parser.It would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might help,

```
[
  {
    //Removes the fields having null from the JSON
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": "=recursivelySquashNulls"
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "*": {
            //Shift only if sourcePguid is present
            "sourcePguid": {
              "@": "&4.sourcePguid",
              "@(1,factvalue)": "&4.@(2,Factname)"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    // Select the first element from sourcePguid array shifted
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "sourcePguid": "=firstElement(@(1,sourcePguid))"
      }
    }
}
]
```